# Create PriorityQueue from Comparator and Collection

Tags: java, android

I have a Collection (a Set to be specific) and want to create a PriorityQueue from it. I also want my custom comparator, but there's no such constructor.

```
PriorityQueue(Collection c)
PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator comparator)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Is there any way to first create the PriorityQueue from the Collection and then add the Comparator later? If no, what's the most efficient way to add it "manually"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options:

1. Use the [`PriorityQueue(Collection c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28java.util.Collection%29) constructor and let the elements in the collection implement the [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. (And let the priority queue fall back on [the natural ordering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of the elements).
2. Use the [`PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) constructor, and then add all the elements of the collection, preferrably using the [`PriorityQueue.addAll(Collection c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the second constructor and then call `addAll(Collection col)` method

Comment: If you omit the time complexity, then that's ok. Note that addAll costs `O(nlogn)` where `n` is the size of the parameter of `addAll()`. If one want `O(n)` build time instead, `addAll()` is not the way you should go.

Answer (score 0):

If your set is a SortedSet with your Comparator, then PriorityQueue will automatically set your custom Comparator to the PriorityQueue.

Line 403:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.java.html